# how to insert 2 elements after each element in a for-loop on a list?

Tags: python, list, insert

I need a list of coordinates to be extended by two new coordinates after each original coordinate in order to keep a "drawing" order.

I have read and understand that a simple loop will run into an infinite loop that is why I am using enumerate over the first list and insert/append to second list.

NOTE: 'lc' and 'rc' in the loop is used to test and show this!

```
coords=([100,100,10], [100,101,10], [100,102,10])
print (coords)
coords_n=[]

for idx,val in enumerate(coords):
  print (idx,val)
  coords_n.insert(idx, [val[0], val[1], val[2]])
  lc= [val[0]-50, val[1], val[2]+40, 'lc']
  coords_n.insert(idx+1,lc)
  rc= [val[0]+50, val[1], val[2]+40, 'rc']
  coords_n.insert(idx+2,rc)

print (coords_n)
```

The results are a list but in a wrong order with the new elements at the end of list.

```
new List:
0 [100, 100, 10]
1 [100, 101, 10]
2 [100, 102, 10]
3 [50, 102, 50, 'lc']
4 [150, 102, 50, 'rc']
5 [50, 101, 50, 'lc']
6 [150, 101, 50, 'rc']
7 [50, 100, 50, 'lc']
8 [150, 100, 50, 'rc']
```

Thus, 3 + 4 should be at position 1 +2 followed by 1 and 5+6 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just meant to use `append` instead of `insert`

try this:

```py
coords=([100,100,10], [100,101,10], [100,102,10])
print (coords)
coords_n=[]

for val in coords:
  coords_n.append([val[0], val[1], val[2]])
  lc= [val[0]-50, val[1], val[2]+40, 'lc']
  coords_n.append(lc)
  rc= [val[0]+50, val[1], val[2]+40, 'rc']
  coords_n.append(rc)

print (coords_n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `list.append` function instead of fiddling with insert and position

```py
coords=([100,100,10], [100,101,10], [100,102,10])
coords_n=[]

for [x, y, z] in coords:
    lc = [x - 50, y, z + 40, 'lc']
    rc = [x + 50, y, z + 40, 'rc']
    coords_n.append([x, y, z])
    coords_n.append(lc)
    coords_n.append(rc)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(coords_n)
```